# ModuleNotFoundError for function in module that's been included in __init__.py file

Tags: python

I'm having problems getting a function to import correctly and I'm not sure why.

Right now I have a file structure that looks like this:

```
utils/
  - __init__
  - metrics
  - processing
__init__
decision_tree
```

In my `decision_tree.py` file, I have the following import statement at the top:

```
from utils import mse, majority_vote, gini
```

And when I run `decision_tree.py` I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'processing'
```

In the traceback it mentions the following line in `metrics.py`:

```
File "C:\Users\Jonat\OneDrive\Dokumentumok\Python Scripts\easyml\utils\metrics.py", line 8, in <module>
from processing import get_counts
```

In my `init.py` file in the utils file, I have the following content:

```
from .processing import *
from .metrics import *
```

The `init.py` file in the root directory is empty.

What's more, when I go to the `metrics.py` file and run it, I don't get the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

So why is it that when I run `metrics.py` the import statement works fine, but when I access `metrics.py` through an external file via `init.py` I get the error, even though I've specified for everything to be included in both the `processing` and the `metrics` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from .processing import *` gets the importable names *inside the processing module*, but not the name `processing` itself.

It's kind of like opening a box, finding five more boxes inside it, putting those five boxes in your pocket, and then throwing the original box away.

The import works when you execute `metrics.py` as a standalone module because you're in the `utils/` directory, and `sys.path` includes the current directory.

Comment: What change should I make to allow my function in `metrics.py` that's calling a function within `processing.py` to work when I import it in `decision_tree.py?`

Comment: The easiest way would be to add the `utils` directory to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @JohnGordon: That is the absolute last resort. Relative imports in `metrics.py` should work just fine if run with `python3 -m easyml.utils.metrics` if the root of `easyml` is in your Python path; you don't want to be adding all levels of a directory tree to `PYTHONPATH`. `PYTHONPATH` is a hack that you resort to when you don't understand how to make and install a package.